# Text info extraction from pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfclown

How can I extract text information such as text positional coordinates, width, height and e.t.c., ??
 I tried this with **'Pdf clown'** library and It works perfectly fine for normal text, but, for  **rotated text** (90/-90degrees) it outputs width/height as **0**(zero).

And the **scaling factors** (scaleX, scaleY) for texts with (90/-90 deg) are displaying as (0, 0) repectively, where as for inverted texts ( rotated with 180deg) it is (-1, -1).

I want info for rotated text to highlight them (as width value is zero, I am unable to highlight them). Please help me. I'm working on .NET environment.

**File I am using:** https://nofile.io/f/Kvf2DkXvfj4/edit9.pdf

**Code:** Using [**TextInfoExtractionSample.cs**](https://github.com/n9/pdfclown/blob/master/dotNET/pdfclown.samples.cli/src/org/pdfclown/samples/cli/TextInfoExtractionSample.cs) from pdfclown samples

**Output** 
 (for three various alignments of text in the file above)

Text [x:283,y:104,w:126,h:-23] [font size:-24 , font sytle : ArialMT]: inverted_text

Text [x:265,y:244,w:0,h:121] [font size:0 , font sytle : ArialMT]: vertical_text

Text [x:347,y:131,w:0,h:167] [font size:0 , font sytle : ArialMT]: vertical_minus90

Comment: **A** requests for library recommendations are off topic on stack overflow. There is a dedicated software recommendations stack exchange site.  **B** a valid question would have been, though, a question focusing on your issues with pdf clown.

Comment: Hi @mkl , I've edited the question. Please clarify me about the pdfclown, whether it has any bugs regarding getting rotated text info. Thank you.

Comment: Please share a PDF with "rotated text (90/-90degrees)" and your pivotal code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @mkl Added references ( file and code) to the question. Please check them and help me. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce the problem. Actually there is a problem not only with 90° rotated text but with all not upright text, the effect merely is worst at 90°. Just to be sure, which PDF Clown version do you use? Some NuGet package? Or some self-compiled library? In that case, which branch in which version did you compile?

Comment: I'm in the process of adapting the sources to understand rotation. It will take a bit, though.

Comment: Hi @mkl , I am using self-compiled library which the code was taken directly from this [link](https://sourceforge.net/p/clown/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/). I think that is the last updated version of pdfclown. And thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah ok. I wondered because you referenced the above example via a github repo fork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As I'm more at home with Java than .Net, I analyzed the problem and created a first workaround in PDF Clown / Java; I'll try and port it to .Net later. It shouldn't be too difficult, though, to do it yourself.*

## The issue

The sample file you provided makes the issue pretty clear when running it through the PDF Clown `TextInfoExtractionSample`.

Screenshot of `edit9.pdf`:

[image: screen shot of original]

Screenshot of `edit9.pdf` after applying `TextInfoExtractionSample`:

[image: screen shot after applying <code>TextInfoExtractionSample</code>]

#### Upright text

Everything looks ok.

#### Upside down text

The individual character boxes (green) look ok but the box for the whole string "inverted_text" (dashed black) excludes the outermost characters.

#### Vertical text

The individual character boxes are reduced to 0x0 rectangles (invisible in the screen shot but apparent in content stream analysis). The box for the whole string is reduced to a line (dashed black) on the *base line* of the string missing a bit length.

#### Text at angles in-between

The character boxes are upright, parallel to the page borders, with their base line segment inside the box. As the text is at an angle, though, the upper and lower parts of the characters partially are outside their respective character box while neighboring characters are partially inside.

The boxes for the whole strings also are parallel to the page.

#### In a nutshell

The text character and string boxes only work properly for upright text.

#### In the sources

This matches what one finds in the source code:

- The Java `Rectangle2D` and .Net `RectangleF` classes used for the character boxes by design are meant for rectangles parallel to the coordinate system axes and are used in that manner in PDF Clown. Thus, they *cannot* properly represent width and height of characters at arbitrary angles.
- PDF Clown classes don't include an `Angle` attribute to represent the rotation of the character.
- The calculation of the character box dimensions only takes the values on the main diagonal of the aggregated transformation matrix into account, i.e. `ScaleX` and `ScaleY`, and ignores `ShearX` and `ShearY`. For text which is not upright or upside down, though, `ShearX` and `ShearY` are important, for vertical text `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` are 0.
- The transition from baseline (native PDF way of positioning text) to top-of-character (PDF Clown text positioning) is done by change of y coordinate alone and, therefore, only works properly for upright and upside down text.

## A work-around

A real fix of the issue would require using a completely different class for character and string boxes, a class that models rectangles at arbitrary angles.

A quicker work-around, though, can be to add an `angle` member to the `TextChar`  class and to `ITextString` and implementations, and then to consider that angle when processing the boxes. This work-around is implemented here.

*As already mentioned above, the work-around is first implemented in Java.*

### In Java

First we add an angle member to `TextChar`, calculate correct values for box dimensions and the angle in `ShowText` operation class, and correctly set these values in the `ContentScanner.TextStringWrapper`.

Then we add an angle getter to `TextStringWrapper` (and `ITextString` in general) which returns the angle of the first text char of the string. And we improve the `TextStringWrapper` method `getBox` to take the angle of the text chars into account when determining the string box.

Finally we'll extend the `TextInfoExtractionSample` to take the angle values into account when drawing the boxes.

*I named that angle member `Alpha` as I named that angle α in my sketches. At hindsight `Theta` or simply `Angle` would have been more appropriate.*

#### TextChar

New member variable `alpha`

```java
  private final double alpha;
```

A new and a changed constructor

```java
  // <constructors>
  public TextChar(
    char value,
    Rectangle2D box,
    TextStyle style,
    boolean virtual
    )
  {
      this(value, box, 0, style, virtual);
  }

  public TextChar(
    char value,
    Rectangle2D box,
    double alpha,
    TextStyle style,
    boolean virtual
    )
  {
    this.value = value;
    this.box = box;
    this.alpha = alpha;
    this.style = style;
    this.virtual = virtual;
  }
  // </constructors>
```

A getter for the angle

```java
  public double getAlpha() {
      return alpha;
  }
```

*([TextChar.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/pdfclown/blob/develop/java/pdfclown.lib/src/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/TextChar.java#L38))*

#### ShowText

Update inner interface `IScanner` method `scanChar` to transport the angle

```java
void scanChar(
  char textChar,
  Rectangle2D textCharBox,
  double alpha
  );
```

*([ShowText.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/pdfclown/blob/develop/java/pdfclown.lib/src/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/objects/ShowText.java#L54) inner interface `IScanner`)*

Update `scan` method to correctly calculate rectangle dimensions and angle and forward them to the `IScanner` implementation

```java
[...]
for(char textChar : textString.toCharArray())
{
  double charWidth = font.getWidth(textChar) * scaledFactor;

  if(textScanner != null)
  {
    /*
      NOTE: The text rendering matrix is recomputed before each glyph is painted
      during a text-showing operation.
    */
    AffineTransform trm = (AffineTransform)ctm.clone(); trm.concatenate(tm);
    double charHeight = font.getHeight(textChar,fontSize);

    // vvv--- changed
    double ascent = font.getAscent(fontSize);
    double x = trm.getTranslateX() + ascent * trm.getShearX();
    double y = contextHeight - trm.getTranslateY() - ascent * trm.getScaleY();
    double dx = charWidth * trm.getScaleX();
    double dy = charWidth * trm.getShearY();
    double alpha = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    double w = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    dx = charHeight * trm.getShearX();
    dy = charHeight * trm.getScaleY();
    double h = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    Rectangle2D charBox = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h);

    textScanner.scanChar(textChar,charBox, alpha);
    // ^^^--- changed
  }

  /*
    NOTE: After the glyph is painted, the text matrix is updated
    according to the glyph displacement and any applicable spacing parameter.
  */
  tm.translate(charWidth + charSpace + (textChar == ' ' ? wordSpace : 0), 0);
}
[...]
```

*([ShowText.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/pdfclown/blob/develop/java/pdfclown.lib/src/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/objects/ShowText.java#L129))*

#### ContentScanner inner class TextStringWrapper

Update `TextStringWrapper` constructor `ShowText.IScanner` callback to accept the angle argument and use it for constructing the `TextChar`

```java
getBaseDataObject().scan(
  state,
  new ShowText.IScanner()
  {
    @Override
    public void scanChar(
      char textChar,
      Rectangle2D textCharBox,
      double alpha
      )
    {
      textChars.add(
        new TextChar(
          textChar,
          textCharBox,
          alpha,
          style,
          false
          )
        );
    }
  }
  );
```

A getter for the angle

```java
public double getAlpha() {
    return textChars.isEmpty() ? 0 : textChars.get(0).getAlpha();
}
```

A `getBox` implementation that takes the angle into account

```java
public Rectangle2D getBox(
  )
{
  if(box == null)
  {
    AffineTransform rot = null;
    Rectangle2D tempBox = null;
    for(TextChar textChar : textChars)
    {
      Rectangle2D thisBox = textChar.getBox();
      if (rot == null) {
          rot = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(textChar.getAlpha(), thisBox.getX(), thisBox.getY());
          tempBox = (Rectangle2D)thisBox.clone();
      } else {
          Point2D corner = new Point2D.Double(thisBox.getX(), thisBox.getY());
          rot.transform(corner, corner);
          tempBox.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(corner.getX(), corner.getY(), thisBox.getWidth(), thisBox.getHeight()));
      }
    }
    if (tempBox != null) {
        try {
            Point2D corner = new Point2D.Double(tempBox.getX(), tempBox.getY());
            rot.invert();
            rot.transform(corner, corner);
            box = new Rectangle2D.Double(corner.getX(), corner.getY(), tempBox.getWidth(), tempBox.getHeight());
        } catch (NoninvertibleTransformException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
  return box;
}
```

*([ContentScanner.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/pdfclown/blob/develop/java/pdfclown.lib/src/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/ContentScanner.java#L835) inner class `TextStringWrapper`)*

#### ITextString

New angle getter

```java
  public double getAlpha();
```

*([ITextString.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/pdfclown/blob/develop/java/pdfclown.lib/src/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/ITextString.java#L60))*

#### TextExtractor inner class TextString

New angle getter

```java
public double getAlpha() {
    return textChars.isEmpty() ? 0 : textChars.get(0).getAlpha();
}
```

*([TextExtractor.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/pdfclown/blob/develop/java/pdfclown.lib/src/org/pdfclown/tools/TextExtractor.java#L124))*

#### TextInfoExtractionSample

Changes to `extract` to properly use the angle in outlining the boxes

```java
[...]
for (ContentScanner.TextStringWrapper textString : text.getTextStrings())
{
    Rectangle2D textStringBox = textString.getBox();
    System.out.println("Text [" + "x:" + Math.round(textStringBox.getX()) + "," + "y:" + Math.round(textStringBox.getY()) + "," + "w:"
            + Math.round(textStringBox.getWidth()) + "," + "h:" + Math.round(textStringBox.getHeight()) + "] [font size:"
            + Math.round(textString.getStyle().getFontSize()) + "]: " + textString.getText());

    // Drawing text character bounding boxes...
    colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % textCharBoxColors.length;
    composer.setStrokeColor(textCharBoxColors[colorIndex]);
    for (TextChar textChar : textString.getTextChars())
    {
        // vvv--- changed
        Rectangle2D box = textChar.getBox();
        composer.beginLocalState();
        AffineTransform rot = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(textChar.getAlpha());
        composer.applyMatrix(rot.getScaleX(), rot.getShearY(), rot.getShearX(), rot.getScaleY(),
                box.getX(), composer.getScanner().getContextSize().getHeight() - box.getY());
        composer.add(new DrawRectangle(0, - box.getHeight(), box.getWidth(), box.getHeight()));

        composer.stroke();
        composer.end();
        // ^^^--- changed
    }

    // Drawing text string bounding box...
    composer.beginLocalState();
    composer.setLineDash(new LineDash(new double[] { 5 }));
    composer.setStrokeColor(textStringBoxColor);
    // vvv--- changed
    AffineTransform rot = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(textString.getAlpha());
    composer.applyMatrix(rot.getScaleX(), rot.getShearY(), rot.getShearX(), rot.getScaleY(),
            textStringBox.getX(), composer.getScanner().getContextSize().getHeight() - textStringBox.getY());
    composer.add(new DrawRectangle(0, - textStringBox.getHeight(), textStringBox.getWidth(), textStringBox.getHeight()));
    // ^^^--- changed
    composer.stroke();
    composer.end();
}
[...]
```

*([TextInfoExtractionSample](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfclown0/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfclown0/extract/TextInfoExtractionSample.java#L132) method `extract`)*

### The result

Both character boxes and string boxes now are as intended:

[image: Screenshot with the work-around in action]

So width and height outputs now also are ok:

```java
Text [x:415,y:104,w:138,h:23] [font size:-24]: inverted_text
Text [x:247,y:365,w:128,h:23] [font size:0]: vertical_text
Text [x:364,y:131,w:180,h:23] [font size:0]: vertical_minus90
```

Comment: Thanks a million @mkl !! Now, I understood the real problem and your explanation is very clear though.
I am really happy to see this fixed and I will try to implement the same in .Net and will update here on the same. Thank you very much :-)